# DotNet HttpClient.DefaultProxy Property not reading system settings on Win10

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, dotnet-httpclient, proxy-authentication

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-5.0) indicate, that the default Proxy-Setup for the HttpClient will be determined through the presence of environmental variables and/or the system wide proxy settings.

I set the proxy-auth credentials like this:
`setx http_proxy http://user:password@proxyIP:proxyPort/`, and to be sure rebootet the system.
Since the Windows proxy-settings dialog does not allow to set username and password, i included there the proxy address and port.

Now i try to read them back though the CredentialCache with my C# app.

However the CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials are still empty and the proxy blocks and responds with 407 exceptions. Which is correct, since i cannot pass the credentials.

How do i have to setup the username and password to be able to read them from the CredentialCache?

I would like to be able to go this way, since very old code, long time ago shipped to customers, using a WebRequest object together with this settings  is able to go through.:

```
        UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Thats why i would like to also be able to write somethin to Windows that in turn gets read out of the Cache.

Comment: Do you need to use HTTPS (secure) URL or HTTP URL?

Comment: as a kind of prove-of-concept i would be ok with http.

Comment: Most server these days require HTTPS.